# How to set up Automatic NDK Builds in Eclipse windows?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, android-ndk, installation

I am setting up ndk environment for android while am doing it . It gives error like following please help me. thanks.

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Integrated External Tool Builder' on project 'HelloNDK'.
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\micro8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build" (in directory "C:\Users\micro8\Workspace\HelloNDK"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
Exception occurred executing command line.
Cannot run program "C:\Users\micro8\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8e\ndk-build" (in directory "C:\Users\micro8\Workspace\HelloNDK"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question is how to set up Ndk Build in Eclipse Windows "Automatically" here is the procedure of doing so.If you follow it you won't need to build your Ndk every time you change your files that are stored into your jni folder.And try please to provide us with a more comprehensive title for optimal results in yourquestion . :)

http://mobilepearls.com/labs/ndk-builder-in-eclipse/

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows you should run `ndk-buil.cmd` not `ndk-build`